# Applying permutations with moves rather than swaps

Tags: permutations, performance

Everything I can easily find on applying permutations in-place relies on treating swaps as elementary operations. But in reality, every swap requires at least two moves (to move the first item into the se ond place and the second item into the first place), and we should be able to do better than that when permuting more than 2 items, by eliminating intermediate moves that don't put an item in its final position.

So, given an arbitrary permutation, what is the most efficient algorithm for applying that permutation to an array in terms of minimizing the number of moves?

Comment: In your scheme, how do you move an element from one position to another without disrupting the element in the new position?

Comment: @barrycarter By storing the data to be overwritten in a temporary location, which costs another move, just as you would typically do as an intermediate step in a two-way stop.

Comment: A swap is a special case of a cycle. The short answer is that the most efficient way to apply a permutation (in the sense of minimising moves) is to follow the cycles in the permutation.